# Add git submodule with files?

Tags: git, git-submodules

Is there a way to add a git submodule with all of its files? I really just need the files as a subdirectory with an easy way to run the update with git fetch and git pull.

I tried git cloning the repository but that added the directory as a submodule without the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you want git subtree merge?

Something like:

```
git subtree add --prefix [submodule name] [submodule url] master
```

See http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/

Answer (score 0):

You should see the submodule files after:

```
 cd /path/to/parent/repo/already/cloned
 git submodule update --init
```

Or, in *one* command, you can clone the parent repo *and* the submodules with:

```
git clone --recursive /url/parent/repo
```

Comment: I need all the actual files checked in. I won't be able to access the submodule remote where this repo is going.